# Static member name lookup from generic lambda in member variable template initializer — compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

The following code compiles on GCC and Clang, but not MSVC:

```
namespace ns {
    struct Foo {
        static void bar() { }

        template <int>
        static inline auto baz = [](auto) {
            bar();
        };
    };

    void(*qux)(int) = Foo::baz<42>;
}
```

MSVC outputs:

```
<source>(7): error C3861: 'bar': identifier not found
<source>(8): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'auto ns::<lambda_1339c3816c4e146ee6a49e0218a2a48b>::operator ()<_T>(_T) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            _T=int
        ]
<source>(8): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'auto ns::<lambda_1339c3816c4e146ee6a49e0218a2a48b>::<lambda_invoker_cdecl><_T>(_T)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _T=int
        ]
<source>(8): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'ns::<lambda_1339c3816c4e146ee6a49e0218a2a48b>::<lambda_typedef_cdecl><int>' being compiled
<source>(8): note: while compiling class template member function 'ns::<lambda_1339c3816c4e146ee6a49e0218a2a48b>::operator unknown-type (__cdecl *)(_T1)(__cdecl *(void) noexcept const)(_T1)'
```

Any of these changes "fixes" the error:

- Making the lambda non-generic
- Making `Foo::baz` a non-template static member variable
- Making `Foo::baz` a static function template that returns the lambda
- Qualifying the call to `bar` as `Foo::bar();`
- Removing `ns`, putting `Foo` and `qux` into the global namespace

This looks like a compiler bug to me. Is it one, or am I witnessing some kind of undefined or implementation-defined behaviour?

[Live example on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PpJrbV)

Comment: Does `Foo::bar();` also work?  Looks like a bug to me in either case.

Comment: @NathanOliver it does! Amazing, I didn't think of this somehow.

Comment: Well, at least you have a work around now \o/